# What is causing ListView to maintain its scroll-position after orientation change?

Tags: android, listview, orientation-changes, scroll-position

I have an Activity containing a ListView. I populate the list view using a SimpleCursorAdapter. When I run the app, I can manually scroll down in the ListView (e.g. to the 10th item). Then when I rotate my phone - this destroys and re-creates my Activity and the ListView is made afresh as expected.

But, on my phone after rotating, the re-created Activity shows my ListView still at my manual scroll position (in this example, the 10th row). I'm pretty sure my code is not calling ListView.setSelection(int) so what is causing this re-positioning of the ListView ?

This might seem pretty handy, but its not what I want. Is it part of ListViews behaviour ? If so, how can stop/override this re-positioning ?

Answer (score 4):

Reading around the topic some more....

View states are stored automatically (including my ListView). This is handled by the default implementation of onSaveInstanceState() / onRestoreInstanceState(). Using the debugger I can see that savedInstanceState includes an entry from my ListView - so that is what is automatically repositioning it. To stop that in my Activity I can just override onSaveInstanceState().

Answer (score 0):

Did you use ListActivity as a base class for your activity? If yes then it's likely the feature as it overrides onRestoreInstanceState. I would try to inherit from simple Activity.

Comment: No, I just have a standard Activity not a ListActivity.

Comment: Then I would try setSelection in Activity.onCreate and/or in Activity.onRestoreInstanceState

Comment: I think you are right, the ListView state is automaticaly set by onSaveInstanceState / onRestoreInstanceState.

Answer (score 0):

`ListView` restores its state (including scroll position) after screen rotation the same way and for the same reason as for example `EditText` preserves the text you typed in it. It is how the Android framework is designed. You can stop this save/restore behavior by setting `android:saveEnabled="false"` attribute for the `ListView` in the xml layout file. Or you can call `setSaveEnabled(false)` method on the `ListView` for the same purpose.